# How to view a Mac's iPhoto library remotely on a Windows computer

Tags: windows, photos.app, sharing

On my Mac, Running OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks, I have my iPhoto library with 10,000+ photos. I am wondering if there is a *convenient* way to view this library remotely on a Windows computer.

I actually can view the Mac's contents in windows by connecting to it as if it were a Windows share. Then, after I map the Mac to my Windows instance as a network share, I can navigate to the path

```
<user name>\Pictures\iPhoto Library\Masters\...
```

and I can find all of the originals. That works ...okay... but it has these challenges:

- iPhoto library divvies up photos in folders on the file system according to when the photos were uploaded to the library. Therefore searching for photos between many folders is based on the date a photo was uploaded rather than the date it was taken.
- The Masters folder has the full size masters of each photo, which tend to be in the 5 - 15MB range. This is a heavy network load if all I want to do is quickly flip through them all (2 - 5 sec to load each photo).
- The Masters folder has a Thumbnail folder counterpart with Thumbnails of all the masters, divvied up also by date of upload. The Thumbnails are nearly identically named to their Masters counterparts. The downside is that the folder structure for all Thumbnails have an additional layer of complexity, making them nearly impossible to easily browse them.

So now when I refer to a *convenient* way to do this, I'd like to basically just browse through them, kinda like I do on the Mac, all at once, broken down by events. I could write a program to do this, but surely one already exists, right? Is Bonjour designed to do this (as in, installing Bonjour for Windows)? Is there another program or setting I need?

Comment: It's possible to set up some software which would enable your Mac to work as a media server, and some options for that have specific support for iPhoto (including the two main ones, Plex and, I believe, Kodi). Do you think that might work for you? If so, I'd be happy to write some instructions.

Comment: @timothymh Yes, I'd be happy to try that solution if it is a matter of steps. It sounds like there is not a built in way to do this, which is okay as long as there is _some_ way to do it -  my solution was going to be to write a program in Java to do a directory scan then sort photos. If some instructions will save me from having to do that, I'm all for it.

Comment: You mentioned that you're on a version of macOS newer than Yosemite, but you said that it's an iPhoto library. Just to confirm, you haven't upgraded your library to Photos? The options are quite different for the two.

Comment: @timothymh I have updated the post.I could have sworn that I upgraded to Yosemite, but I am still back at Mavericks. I am still definitely using iPhoto.